# Klevu not working in Magento

Tags: magento2

After successful Klevu-Magento integration, I am not able to search results. Although it shows powered by Klevu, but still it doesnt work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the incorrect mapping of the custom attributes with Klevu configurations and it was fixed by Klevu support team.